# Understanding 「それが人質の証言では」

Tags: copula

From the first episode of *Death Note*:

> それが人質の証言では

**Question:** I'm familiar with ではない, but don't understand what では alone means here?

Comment: Do you have any more context?

Answer (score 2):

The context is

> では / 追い詰められての /　自殺という事 / でしょうか?
>
> それが人質の証言では / 「犯人は突然倒れた」と

(/ indicates the break in the bubble.)

それが here means something like *but*; here *actually* would fit better. では is で＋は, literally meaning *in, by (the words of the hostages)*.   So the whole line means *Actually, according to the hostages, (they say) "the criminal suddenly fell"*.

Comment: RE the lone "では" at the very beginning of your context: is it meant to attach onto the previously stated sentence?  Meaning literally something like: *"As for and within that (previously stated sentence), ..."*.  Or perhaps more idiomatically: *"Seeing that, ..."*.

Comment: @George It is close to *see that*, *that* referring to the previous sentence. [This dictionary entry](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF) may help.